# email has not been sent successfully, but in the server log it shows the address, the title, and the body without any issue. what might be wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid, mailer, activation

below are the info related to this question:
(1). this is related to chapter 11: Account activation in railstutorial online material created by Dr. Hartl (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/)
specifically, chapter 11.4 Email in production

(2). I did "heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter

(3). if I cut the activation link (URL) which is shown on the server log, and paste to a browser window's address entry, the account is activated successfully.
example of an activation link:
https://chai-shen-gjiang.c9users.io/account_activations/sjns02845-5gp4sFlCfYDQ/edit?email=gjiang.all%40yahoo.com

Comment: Please add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should consider a more succinct title and put the question entirely in the body.